# usage of setOldClass in R

Tags: r, r-s4

I have created a union class

```
setClassUnion("numericOrNULL",members=c("numeric", "NULL"))  
getClass("numericOrNULL")
```

Then I need to use this new class in the slot of an object. At the moment I build the package I get an error. I have found that I can use setOldClass:

```
setOldClass("numericOrNULL")
```

However, this is affecting the definition of the class:

```
getClass("numericOrNULL")
```

and my code doesn't work properly anymore

```
> invalid object for slot "mySlot" in class "myClass": got class
> "numeric", should be or extend class "numericOrNULL"
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered unless you offer the code that is being used. You should also read the second sentence of the Details in the help page.

Comment: The `setOldClass` statement seems unnecessary, so I wonder what the error is in the "I get an error" ?